# Build commands needed to run Wine programs from IDE

Tags: c, linux, gcc, notepad, wine

I’ve recently done a git clone of the wine repository at https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine and downloaded the folders to (~/repo/wine/). I'm trying to run Notepad, but don't know how. I am assuming that to build and compile it, I would need to run main.c from the notepad folder. I’m running GCC v 8.3.0 on Raspbian/Linux 10

With the repo downloaded as shown above, what build commands would I need to run notepad’s main.c from Geanie (or any, currently using Geanie) IDE? Can a single compile and/or build command let me run notepad from Geanie, or am I missing something?

Other details (not needed if what I thought I was going to do can't be done):

I wanted to try to run main.c at (~/repo/wine/programs/main.c), but don’t know how to get GCC to view all of the necessary header files. In my execution instructions window in Geanie, I have

```
gcc -Wall -c “%f” /home/pi/repo/wine/include
```

and my build instruction (it won't compile, so this isn't anything I've even gotten to work with yet...)

```
gcc -Wall -o “%e” “%f” /home/pi/repo/wine/include
```

When I attempt to compile, I get:

```
Stdio.h:11:10: fatal error: corecrt_wstdui.h: No such file or directory.
#include <corecrt_wstudio.h>
```

I went over to the stdio.h and attempted to add a build instruction here as well that also targets the include folder (which is the supposedly missing file), but it won’t compile.

Using cpp -v, I can see my include paths for GCC are as follows:

```
#include”...” paths:
#include<...> paths:
\usr\lib\gcc\arm-linux-gnueabihf\8\include
\usr\local\include
\usr\lib\gcc\arm-linux-gnueabihf\8\include-fixed
\usr\include\arm-linux-gnueabihf
\usr\include
```

Comment: The "notepad" program from wine does not build standalone, you need the whole shebang: `./configure && make`, then run `./wine notepad` to run, well, "notepad". You can run `make -jN` with `N` the number of cores of your CPU to speed things up.

Comment: Ahh...okay. Gotcha. Now that I type that I'm frustrated with myself for being so dang caught up in doing that... I could already run the program like you mention (thankfully without even running that cmd line sequence) and I could just tinker with the files and see how they affect runtime (risky or otherwise). Ugh. Again, thank you!